# Is there a notification mechanism for when getifaddrs() results change?

Tags: c, interface, ipv6, polling

On startup, my program calls getifaddrs() to find out what network interfaces are available for link-local IPv6 multicasting.  This works as far as it goes, but it doesn't handle the case where the set of available network interfaces changes after getifaddrs() has returned.

Is there some way for the OS to notify my program when the network interfaces have changed, so I can call getifaddrs() again and update my list?  Or am I doomed to poll getifaddrs() every few seconds, forever?

(Note:  on Windows, I call GetAdaptersAddresses() instead of getifaddrs(), but the same issue exists there)

Comment: Why would you expect the network interfaces to change so often that you'd have to poll every few seconds? Are you talking about virtual interfaces?

Comment: So far we've mainly seen the problem on MacBooks, where the user has our program running and is turning AirPort on and off, connecting/disconnecting from the wired LAN, enabling/disabling HSPA high-speed wireless, etc.  When this happens, the program starts malfunctioning since it is still trying to use the now-inactive interfaces, and not trying to use the newly active ones.

Comment: Dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579783/how-to-detect-ip-address-change-programmatically-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at the NotifyAddrChange and NotifyIpInterfaceChange functions.

Comment: That's an answer for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Also, the Linux way to implement this is by opening a socket of family AF_NETLINK and subtype NETLINK_ROUTE and reading the messages that arrive on it from the kernel, as shown in the example code included in "man 7 netlink".  (Thanks to Rob Searce for pointing me to that!)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested, I found the following document on Apple's developer site that describes how to get notified when the network configuration changes.  It's non-trivial, but I did get the technique to work for me.  See Listing 8 in particular.

[Technical Note TN1145 - Living in a Dynamic TCP/IP Environment"](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1145.html)

Comment: I think the above link is now dead - I found it on this one http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn1145/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

For Linux:

Use netlink sockets.  They can be used to get notifications of added and removed interfaces and, I think, changes of interface addresses.

For macOS:

Use `PF_SYSTEM` sockets.  They're not well documented, so you may have to poke around to see how to use them.  See comments in the code I point to below.

For *BSD:

Use `PF_ROUTE` sockets.  In addition to new/removed interfaces indications, which are delivered as `RTM_IFANNOUNCE` message, they can deliver address-change notifications as well, as `RTM_NEWADDR`/`RTM_DELADDR` messages.

For the code in Wireshark that listens for new and removed interfaces, which, in the tip of the main branch, does all of the above, see [capture/iface_monitor.c](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/capture/iface_monitor.c?ref_type=heads).  It uses libnl for netlink sockets on Linux, and uses direct socket calls on the other platforms.

For other UN*Xes:

I don't know what Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, or various now-dead UN*Xes offer in that regard.

For Windows:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270654/16139739).