# How to get uptime / creation time for a network interface on linux

Tags: linux, interface, uptime

Could you please help in getting , how to get uptime or creation time for a network interface on linux?

Thanks 
S Sarath

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no standard uptime tracking for network interfaces in Linux. Most linux distributions allow hooks for networking interface events, you can use these for setting your own tracking (these are distro-specific).

See this answer: [Get notified about network interface change on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261759/get-notified-about-network-interface-change-on-linux)