# Monitoring ARP table changes

Tags: c++, linux, arp, netlink

I'm trying to monitor my ARP table in linux using c++ and so far the only solution I have is polling the /proc/net/arp every interval and compare to the previous state.

Can I use netlink sockets in order to receive events from the kernel on these changes?

I have look around and cannot find a straight answer, I found tolls like [ip-monitor](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-monitor.8.html) but didn't found out how they get this data.

If netlink socket cannot provide this information, is there any other way to extract this with events and not polling?

Comment: I can also manage with something like inotify to get event on change and then compare the current state to the previous but inotify can't monitor /proc

Comment: I have found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788326/extract-current-route-from-netlink-message-code-attached) for monitoring routing table changes, can I use the same technique to monitor the ARP table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find how to get events on ARP table changes using netlink socket, the only thing that I have missing is how to extract the ARP details from the event but for now this will do:

```
int sock;
static struct sockaddr_nl g_addr;

/* Zeroing addr */
bzero(&g_addr, sizeof(g_addr));
g_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
g_addr.nl_groups = nl_mgrp(RTNLGRP_NEIGH);

if ((sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE)) < 0) {
    printf("socket() error: %s", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &g_addr, sizeof(g_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("bind() error: %s", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

char buffer[4096];
int received_bytes = 0;

while (true) {
    received_bytes = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (received_bytes > 0) {
        printf("Event\n");
        // How to parse the event
    }
}
```